# filtering out users using TwitterUtils

Tags: java, twitter4j, spark-streaming, twitter-util

Is there a way to extract only specific user who post a tweet when using TwitterUtils.createStream()? (JAVA) 
The "filters" argument specifies the strings that need to be contained in the tweets, but I am not sure how this can be used to specify the user who interest me. 
i have this :

```
String[] filters = { "#USA" };
    JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,filters);
```

this give me tweets which contains "#USA"
what i need is a way to listen to a specific user and see what he post .

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void receive() {
    try {
        TwitterStream newTwitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory()
                .getInstance(twitterAuth);
        newTwitterStream.addListener(new StatusListener() {

            public void onException(Exception e) {
                if (!arret) {
                    restart("Erreur pandant la reception des tweets", e);
                }

            }

            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                store(status);
            }

            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();

        if (filter_mots.length > 0 || filter_utilisateurs.length >0) {
            if (filter_mots.length > 0){
                query.track(filter_mots);   
            }
            if (filter_utilisateurs.length >0){

                query.follow(filter_utilisateurs);  
            }
            newTwitterStream.filter(query);
        } else{
            newTwitterStream.sample();
        }
        setTwitterStream(newTwitterStream) ; 
        arret = false ; 

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // En cas d'erreur on redémare le streaming 
        restart("Erreur pendant la reception des données ", t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter users with Twitter4j you should use TwitterStream, like the code below:

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build())
    .getInstance(); // First you create the Stream

StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
    //... a lot of things
}

twitterStream.addListener(listener);
FilterQuery filtre = new FilterQuery();
filtre.follow(usuarios); //you could filter by users
twitterStream.filter(filtre);
```

In that way you can get the tweets by the users that you want.

You should check [the examples](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/stream) of Twitter4j for the streaming api.

If you want to filters users AND get the tweets that say  "USA" you should filter first the users, and then in the  `StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() { //... a lot of things }` part you can create filters for the tweets that you are receiving.

Comment: i'am using Spark-Streaming and i can't apply your solution because i use this to create a new TwitterStream :                             JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local[2]","TestTwitterStreaming");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(3000));
String[] filters = { "USA" };
JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, filters);

Comment: @sparking Take a look at [`TwitterInputDStream`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/twitter/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterInputDStream.scala#L41) - you could create a similar class that 'follows' rather than 'filters'.